# Upgrade to macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, upgrade

Will my data on the Macbook Pro be destroyed if I upgrade to macOS Sierra from OS X El Capitan?

Answer (score 1):

It will most likely all be there. It will only update the operating system and leave your data untouched. 
It is still a good idea to make a backup in case something goes wrong.

Comment: Provided it goes well. It's always a good idea to have a backup of your files before upgrading anything.